# How to process geo data in hadoop mapreduce

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I have a dataset look like this:

```
ID, X, Y   
1, 59.1308951, 40.5323093   
2, 34.2, 39.9602601   
3, 40.7163491, 48.0147763   
4, 29.961817, -0.4359644   
5, 40.5126881, 40.97465   
6, 40.9933396, 4.5191097   
7, 43.4945737, 39.14
```

`X,Y` values (longitude, latitude) represent a "spot".

What I'm trying to achieve here is to find all "spots" that have a difference of at least distance `(k,l)`.

For example, for "spot" with id 1 which "spots" are close to it by distance `(k,l)`? 
I want to repeat that process for all the "Spots" in my dataset. The problem here is that I can't think the correct key-value conversion in the map/reduce functions.

Any idea? Or anything similar I can read?

Comment: And this has to be done in mapreduce? What is `k`? Sounds like you need a matrix that builds distances between each and every point. In which case, I don't think it's possible for you to have any more than one key since all values must be grouped against another one, so NullWritable could work for a key

Comment: Yes, this has to be done in mapreduce since my dataset is about 1TB and hadoop is the only framework i'm familiar with for big data analysis. k, since you asked, is a distance. And since i have 2d data == vector, a distance between two vectors is again a vector! If i have x=(x1,y1) and y=(x2,y2), the distance between them is (x2-x1,y2-y1) == (k,l). I hope i was clear.

Comment: Let me rephrase. You can still use Hadoop. You don't need to write Java to use MapReduce. In other words, maybe Spark can work better. My point about the matrix is that you would need to build all distances from `(id1,
 {id2..id7})` and `(id2, {id1..id7})`. These are your key pairs.